# cancel AsyncTask class in onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm inspecting other's code. And what I have seen there.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(AutoBookmarkInfo result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // some computation...

        if (setAutoBookmarkTask != null) {
            setAutoBookmarkTask.cancel(false);
            setAutoBookmarkTask = null;
        }

    }
```

`setAutoBookmarkTask` - is an instance of AsyncTask class. 
Please, could someone explains why this guy tries to cancel working thread when all work already have been done ?

Comment: The `setAutoBookmarkTask` could not necessairly be related to this particular `onPostExecute()`, this can be some other `AsyncTask`.

Comment: And I don't running one `AsyncTask` at onPostExecute of another `AsyncTask` is a good idea.

Comment: I think you know about AsynchTask class working flow. As @g00dy said that cancellation code is not necessary to add in onPostExecute() method.If you wantedly cancel the running task you can add into where ever you need within your activity.

Comment: If I understood right, this code is for force cancellaton on thread.

Answer (score 0):

`setAutoBookmarkTask.cancel(false)` doesnot mean anything. If you need to interrupt or cancel the async task you have to pass true in argument.

Comment: you can use like this also http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/